# Performe nested select statement with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I have problem executing nested SELECT statement.
Here is my SQL :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM posts AS p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT u.postId FROM users AS u) ;
```

I'm using MySQL and this is working when I try it with MySQL Workbench
But when I try this in my application in which I'm using Spring JDBC, it throws me "org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException."

Here is how I'm using it in my app:

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(SQL, Integer.class);
```

I had tried and :

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL, new RowCountCallbackHandler());
```

Both ways are not working and I get an error.

Is there are some configuration options or something that will allowed me to execute such 
nested SELECT statements ?

**EDIT**

The error trace is:

```
[3D000]; error code [1046]; No database selected; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No data
base selected
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(Abstrac
tFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(Abstrac
tFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(Abstrac
tFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:411)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:476)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:486)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:492)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't configure your dataSource properly:

example:

```
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
   </bean>
```

You need added **DATABASE NAME** to the **url**, in this case is **TEST**

Comment: Yes, this fix the problem. Can you explain me the problem please and why specify the DB NAME fix it ?

Comment: @MilenYanchev, you need to specify the schema name besides the name of the table.

Comment: That is exactly what I have did. Thank you for helping me with the problem!